# Edit a primary key in CakePHP 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, primary-key, cakephp-3.0

I want to edit the primary key in CakePHP 3 called `WTEL` from the table *Watch*.

The primary key field is hidden by default in the view so I use this code line to make it appear in the file `src/Template/Watch/edit.ctp` (generated by scaffold) :

```
echo $this->Form->input('WTEL', array('type' => 'text'));
```

The field `WTEL` appear but when I modify the `WTEL` input and click on the submit button the `WTEL` value is not modified.

However this code line work for the *add* page for adding the `WTEL` value.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you are hoping to be able to update the Primary Key of an existing row in your edit.ctp view (using the default baked edit function in you Watch Controller)?

The simplest way to do this would be make a 'copy' function, something along these lines:

```
public function copy($id = null){

    //get the old Watch to be copied
    $oldWatch = $this->Watch->get($id);

    $watchTable = TableRegistry::get('Watchs');
    $watch= $watchsTable->newEntity();

    //Copy all existing values into new row, e.g.
    $watch->description = $oldwatch->description;

    if ($watchsTable->save($watch)) {
        // The $watch entity contains the id now, so you are returned 
           to the edit page for the newly created 'watch'
        $id = $watch->id;
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $id]);
}
```

If you wanted to make a custom Primary Key, you could try adding this:

```
$watch->id = $this->data['Watch']['id'];
```

In the 'copy all existing values' section commented above.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do ! If I understand well I have to create a copy function in the WatchController. To call this function I have to replace the link to edit to the link to copy (I will be redirected to the edit page after). I have to create a copy.ctp.

Comment: I make small change in the function like my table is called Watch (I know I should have called it Watchs) so I change : TableRegistry::get('Watchs') to TableRegistry::get('Watch'); and $watchsTable to $watchTable. But I get two error : Notice (8): Undefined variable: oldwatch [APP/Controller/WatchController.php, line 104]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/WatchController.php, line 104]
Thanks for helping ;)